# Overlaping layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have implemented 2 listViews and editText in my fragment. ListViews are reloaded for example when user enter something into editText or select row from left listView. But when I minimalize my application and maximize after 1 hour there are 2 listviews on each and 2 different number in editText (overlaping), one from previous state and one from new. How should I fix it? Remove adapter in `onPause` method and reload in `onStart` and save value from editText? Is the any simpler solution?

setting listener on first listview to reload second one:

```
listViewFrom.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    listViewFrom.setItemChecked(position, true);
    currentUnit = ((FromAdapter.ViewHolder) view.getTag()).getUnit();
    createToList(inputEditText.getText().toString(), currentUnit);
  }
});
```

add listener to edit text:

```
 inputEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    createToList(s.toString(), currentUnit);
  }
});
```

and createToList function:

```
 private void createToList(String string, Unit unit) {
    if (isNumeric(string)) {
       double value = Double.valueOf(string);
       List<Unit> list = createList(value, unit);
       ToAdapter toAdapter = new ToAdapter(list, getActivity());
       listViewTo.setAdapter(toAdapter);
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/inputEditText"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputEditText"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fromListView"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4">

    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/toListView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and how it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Hi falsetto, maybe provide us a bit more of your code, so it's easier to help you. cheers

Comment: Post the code of XML pls

Comment: Try setting your screen-orientation to 'portrait'. And have a re-run.

Comment: The same is happening when I rotate screen, I tried with `onSaveInstanceState` where I set adapter to null but it doesnt help